# SQL запрос неправильно заносит даты

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю вот такой запрос в Pythone к БД SQLite:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO npf_data (id_npf, date, [{r}]) VALUES({q}, {w}, {e})'.\format(r=int(b), q=a, w=df_data_npf['Дата'][j], e=df_data_npf['Показание'][j]))
```

Но дату она дату неправильно заносит(пример в рисунке).

Comment: просмотрите какой тип данных дата в таблице и в каком формате sqlite готов принимать значения для этого типа

Comment: Составлять SQL запросы форматированием очень плохой подход так как ведет к иньекциям, передавайте аргументы кортежем как указано в документации.

Comment: cur.execute('INSERT INTO npf_data (id_npf, date, ['+ b +']) VALUES(?, ?, ?)',(a, df_data_npf['Дата'][j], df_data_npf['Показание'][j]))       - Переписал код на это и сработало. Но в чем разница? Формат даты не менял.

Comment: Без кавычек строка `2010-06-30`воспринимается sqlite'ом, как математическое выражение равное 1974. Стоит помнить о том, что `sqlite` не строго типизированная БД, так что независимо от типа поля он может сохранить в нём любую строку или число. ЗЫ: а `b` не получается что ли подстановкой вставить?

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Спасибо, сейчас понятно. b пытался подставить подстановкой, но не получилось. Хотя мог тоже ошибиться в типах данных.